# Running SSIS packages remotely - what account do they run under?

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I am currently building an application in .NET 4.0 that will use SSIS 2008R2 packages to do its job. The packages are located on a separate SQL Server. The SQL server has an account proxy that has all the permissions needed for the packages to execute (call Reporting services, access disk, etc).

My question is: what is the best way to run those packages from C#?

I read about using SQL Agent to run the packages through jobs but my concern is this - what account will the job and packages use? Will it be the account under which the application is running or I can use the proxy account that I have in SQL Server? How can I configure this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the user that each job step is run under in SQL Server agent. It is common to use the proxy user here.

An easy way to start the jobs in case you need SQL Server database access anyway is via calling the [SQL Server Agent system stored procedures](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187763.aspx). But note that starting a  job via `dbo.sp_start_job` is asynchronous: It just starts the job and then returns. You will have to poll other methods to check the job status or outcome.

And the database user that you are using to connect to the database (or your local user in case you use integrated login to SQL Server) must have the permission to call the stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Does this mean that if I create the Agent job with the necessary proxy user and then execute it remotely from C#, it will use this user to run the package and not the one the C# process is running under? I am referring to this article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403355%28v=sql.105%29.aspx which mentions process permissions.

Comment: As I understand it, they are exactly suggesting to use a SQL Server agent job in order to make use of the feature that this runs under a different user on the remote computer.

Comment: Perhaps I did not understand the correct meaning. Thanks for the assistance, will post back if any differences appear.